# Writing data through the network

Tags: java, c#

I'm working on a basic networking implementation in C# that will allow me to send data to my Java server. The Server has been tested for quite some time and does everything that it needs to do with a Java client, and now I'm trying to learn about C# client development.

The issue that I'm running into is that the server is reading every packet opcode I send through the C# client as 0, thus not performing any logic. The data is read on the server as a byte. Here's my setup for

```
public class NetworkClient {

    public static NetworkClient Create() {
        return new NetworkClient ();
    }

    private Queue<Task> tasks = new Queue<Task>();

    private String HostAddress = "localhost";

    private int Port = 5055;

    private TcpClient _tcpClient;

    private NetworkStream _networkStream;

    private NetworkClient() {

    }

    public void Update() {
        while (tasks.Count > 0) 
            tasks.Dequeue () ();
    }

    public void Submit(Task task) {
        tasks.Enqueue (task);
    }

    public NetworkClient SetPort(int port) {
        Port = port;
        return this;
    }

    public NetworkClient SetHostAddress(String hostAddress) {
        HostAddress = hostAddress;
        return this;
    }

    public NetworkClient Connect() {
        _tcpClient = new TcpClient (HostAddress, Port);
        _networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream ();
        return this;
    }

    public bool IsConnected() {
        return _tcpClient.Connected;
    }

    public NetworkClient Disconnect() {
        _tcpClient.Close ();
        return this;
    }

    public void Write(Packet packet) {
        _networkStream.Write (packet.buffer.ToArray (), 0, (int)packet.buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Here's the Packet class:

```
public class Packet {
    public int Opcode;
    public MemoryStream buffer;

    public static Packet Create(int opcode) {
        return new Packet (opcode, 128);
    }

    public static Packet Create(int opcode, int capacity) {
        return new Packet (opcode, capacity);
    }

    private Packet(int opcode, int capacity) {
        Opcode = opcode;
        buffer = new MemoryStream(capacity);
    }

    public Packet Write(Object o) {
        byte[] b = ObjectToByteArray (o);
        buffer.Write (b, 0, b.Length);
        return this;
    }

    private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is called and executed to send a packet to the server with the following code:

```
public static void Main() {
        NetworkClient client = NetworkClient.Create ().Connect ();
        Packet packet = Packet.Create (1);
        packet.Write ((byte)3);
        packet.Write (100L);
        packet.Write (100L);
        packet.Write (100L);
        packet.Write (1840979156127491L);
        client.Write (packet);
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
```

This should write a byte(the opcode, with a value of 3), and then 4 longs(Int64) over the network. A total size of 33 bytes.

The server however is reading 282 bytes.

Executing the following code (**Java**) which basically does the same thing,reads the correct amount of data (33 bytes) and processes it correctly.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(65);
                buffer.put((byte) 3); //opcode
                buffer.putLong(100L);
                buffer.putLong(100L);
                buffer.putLong(100L);
                buffer.putLong(1840979156127491L);
                buffer.flip();
                channel.write(buffer);
                buffer.compact();
```

If anyone could assist me I'd be very greatful.

Comment: What does `ObjectToByteArray` do? You seem to be calling that for each byte/long.

Comment: Sorry, added it to the question

Comment: @immibis -- Ahaha, removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `BinaryFormatter` to write raw data. [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the way to go. It allows you to write the data without any object information, so a byte will be a byte, an int will be an int and a string will be a string with only length information encoded before it.

So you can remove the whole `ObjectToByteArray` method, create a `BinaryWriter` object when you create the `MemoryStream` and just `Write()` the data into it. In the end you have everything you need in the `MemoryStream` and it will be a lot more efficient than the current one creating many temporary objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `packet.Write((byte)3);` in your code, that doesn't actually write a single byte. Instead, it writes a serialized object (which happens to be a byte) - in actual terms, this will be the byte itself, plus several bytes surrounding it to basically say "This is a byte".

Same for the `long` values.

Why not have a look at what `b` contains in your `Write` method? It will be more data than you expected.

Comment: How can I go about resolving this? I'm not very good with C# at all and quite frankly don't like the language, unfortunately it's just something I'll have to overcome. 

I have a Stream i created by referecing the Java's DataOutputStream, however it's really complicated. Trying to find a way to do this easily using standard C# code.

Comment: @Christian.tucker For the byte, write it directly to the buffer. For the longs, I don't know either whether C# has an equivalent of DataOutputStream.